# What is the needed to call for calculating num_ftrs in efficient_b4

Tags: python, pytorch, transfer-learning

I am recently trying to solve an image classification problem using transfer learning with the help of `efficient_b4` CNN. While calculating the number of features of the last fully connected layer I am facing an error. Here is my code :

```
model = models.efficientnet_b4(pretrained = True)
num_ftrs = model.fc.in_features
```

> AttributeError: 'EfficientNet' object has no attribute 'fc'

Can anyone please help me to calculate `num_ftrs`.

Answer (score 0):

It's because Efficient Net last layer is '**classifier**', not '**fc**'. When printing the model structure, you will see

```
(classifier): Sequential(
    (0): Dropout(p=0.4, inplace=True)
    (1): Linear(in_features=1792, out_features=1000, bias=True)
 )
```

So you can get `num_ftrs` by

```
num_ftrs = model.classifier[1].in_features
```